# logical-deduction vs logic-theory

Tags: support, retagging

What's the difference between the tags `logical-deduction` and `logic-theory`?

Are they both needed?

And if they are, wouldn't it make more sense for them to both start with either `logical-` or `logic-`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, [logic-theory] is hardly used at all and has no official description. It looks to me as if its actual uses break down as follows:

- Some cases of outright misuse, on what are actually just arithmetic puzzles
- Some things that might reasonably be tagged [logical-deduction]
- One question that's actually *about logic* rather than merely *using logic* ... which has been closed as being really a mathematics question rather than a puzzle.

I think [logic-theory] could reasonably be done away with. Anyone want to object before I do it?

[EDITED to add:] OK, I did it. The [logic-theory] tag is gone. If anyone *really* wants to make puzzles for which it would have been appropriate, and can do so without getting them closed as "textbook mathematics problem rather than puzzle", and really wants a specific tag, then I suggest that [mathematical-logic] would be better.

Comment: No objection here.

Comment: Do it!  Burninate!

Comment: Nice work......